# Create .txt of all files in each subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a text file in each subdirectory of all files in the list.
For example, `subdirectory1` would contain a list of all of its files as a `.txt` and `subdirectory2` would also contain a list of all of `subdirectory2` files as a `.txt`.
I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in "$directory" *
do  
    if [ -d "$X" ];
    then
        cd "$X"
        files="$(ls)"
        echo "$files" >> filesNames.txt
    fi
done
```

However this did not generate anything.  I absolutely need it as a shell script because it will be part of a pipeline script, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is the adjusted script giving me the no such file or directory comment.  I know that the folder exists and have used it in commands that are run before this command.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Retrieve the base directory path
baseDir=$(dirname "$ini")

#Retrieve the reference genome path
ref=$(dirname "$genome")

#Create required directory structure
tested="$baseDir/tested"
MarkDups1="$baseDir/MarkDups1"

#don't create if already exists
[[ -d "tested" ]] || mkdir "$tested"
[[ -d "MarkDups1" ]] || mkdir "$MarkDups1"


#create a text file with all sorted and indexed bam files paths
#!/bin/bash
for x in $MarkDups1/*/;
do
    (cd "$x"; ls > filesNames.txt)
done
```

Comment: `[[ -d "$tested" ]]` and `[[ -d "$MarkDups1" ]]`; you are currently testing for two literal directory names, not the names stored in the two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence to iterate over should be `"$directory"/*/`.

```
for x in "$directory"/*/; do
  (cd "$x"
   files=(*)
   printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" > filesNames.txt
  )
done
```

Comment: Just curious, are there significant reasons for this style method (_for_ loop with subshell) over, say, `find` and xargs/pipes et cetera ? Except to keep questioner in flow

Comment: I went a little overboard on the unnecessary changes. The subshell just prevents the need to `cd` back to the original, if `x` isn't an absolute path name. The rest just avoids calling any external programs, although since we aren't actually parsing the output of `ls`, `files=$(ls); echo "$files" > filesNames.txt` wouldn't be the worst thing you could do.

Comment: If you don't care about `filesNames.txt` being listed in itself, you can just use `ls > filesNames.txt` instead.

Comment: It's now telling me ``No such file or directory``.  I am not new, but not an expert either, at shell bash and I am really stumped on this one.  Here is the script with the definitions for each folder that I am working in- the full paths are linked in with the .ini file and work as I have exectued earlier parts of my script without any problems.  I am building the script for a very large dataset and want to test each section on a subset before executing on everything and as such am testing each part separately for now.  Earlier parts run fine, just getting stumped here

Comment: I have added the full and adjusted script to my question (see bottom script)

Comment: Awesome! That last adjustment you made worked.  Thank-you so much